# How to include jQuery and Semantic-ui in Webpack Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, semantic-ui

I'm new to Webpack and using it for an Angular2 project (https://angularclass.github.io/angular2-webpack-starter/).

I'm having a hard time getting jQuery and Semantic-ui to work (both .css and .js) after `npm install`ing it. I suppose it's somewhat problematic because both libraries are not in any module format, and can not simply be `require(...)`ed or `import`ed

Do I need to include them simply in the `index.html` as normal , or is there a 'Webpack way' to do this ?

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Install Semantic-UI using npm: `npm install semantic-ui --save` 
   and follow the instructions during the installation process. 
   I installed it under `src/assets`.
2. "Build" Semantic using `gulp build` inside its directory. 
   This will create another directory under `/semantic` called `dist` or whatever name you set as output directory during the installation process.
3. Now we will have to tell Webpack to load Semantic's .js and .css files (the ones in the newly created `/semantic/dist/` directory). 
   I generated my project using `angular-cli`and have my configs in the root directory in a file called `angular-cli.json`. 
   It looks like this: 
   https://gist.github.com/olegkorol/d77951e3ba3a5ff2c798e96c807c1a02 
   Look for "styles" and "scripts" in the JSON and add Semantic's minified .css and .js respectively: 
   `"assets/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css"` 
   and 
   `"assets/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"`
4. As you already stated in your question, Semantic-UI needs jQuery in order to work. 
    We will just add the script to the <.head> of `index.html` (in the `/src` directory): 
   `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`
5. Build or serve your app again and you should have Semantic-UI working properly ;) 

   Hope this helps.

Comment: I have followed these steps and semantic ui styles are loading fine, but the  scripts are not working, I have added an `accordion` but the click doesn't  open and collapse the sections. What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you sure you also added "assets/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"?

Comment: yes, I have included it, and also jquery in index.html